# Работа с множествами в С++

Tags: c++, stl

Требуется написать функцию пересечения двух множеств, но возникла проблема, как проверять, что в одном множестве есть данный элемент а в другом нет? Нашел функцию `find()`, но она возвращает итератор с указанием на элемент множества. А если данного элемента нет, то что тогда она вернет?

Comment: Разве в справочнике не написано? Cont.end();

Comment: А готовая [set_intersection](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) не годится?

Answer (score 2):

Если не годится готовая `set_intersection`, то вот вариант ее реализации:

```
template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2, class OutputIt>
OutputIt set_intersection(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
                          InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2,
                          OutputIt d_first)
{
    while (first1 != last1 && first2 != last2) {
        if (*first1 < *first2) {
            ++first1;
        } else  {
            if (!(*first2 < *first1)) {
                *d_first++ = *first1++;
            }
            ++first2;
        }
    }
    return d_first;
}
```

Если ваши множества отсортированы (например, если это реальные *set*), то это то, что нужно. Если под множеством вы понимаете, например, массив или вектор - сначала их отсортируйте.

Для... гм... новичков... разжевываю тут: http://ideone.com/fFbU9L

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    set<string> a{"aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee","fff"};
    set<string> b{"ddd","eee","fff","ggg","hhh","iii"};

    set<string> res;
    set_intersection(a.begin(),a.end(),b.begin(),b.end(),
                     inserter(res,res.begin()));
    for(auto s: res) cout << s << endl;

    cout << "----------\n";

    set<const char*> c{"aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee","fff"};
    set<const char*> d{"ddd","eee","fff","ggg","hhh","iii"};

    set<const char*> r;
    set_intersection(c.begin(),c.end(),d.begin(),d.end(),
                     inserter(r,r.begin()),[](const char*x,const char*y){ return strcmp(x,y) < 0; });
    for(auto s: r) cout << s << endl;

    cout << "----------\n";

    vector<const char*> e{"aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee","fff"};
    vector<const char*> f{"ddd","eee","fff","ggg","hhh","iii"};

    sort(e.begin(),e.end(),[](const char*x,const char*y){ return strcmp(x,y) < 0; });
    sort(f.begin(),f.end(),[](const char*x,const char*y){ return strcmp(x,y) < 0; });

    vector<const char*> g;
    set_intersection(e.begin(),e.end(),f.begin(),f.end(),
                     back_inserter(g),[](const char*x,const char*y){ return strcmp(x,y) < 0; });
    for(auto s: g) cout << s << endl;

}
```

Comment: только что узнал о данной функции. Попытался использовать, но в ответ получил ошибку 
Ошибка 1 error C2039: push_back: не является членом "std::set<_Kty>" d:\vs2012ultimate\vc\include\iterator 33

Вот код реализации, где А, В, G - set

set_intersection(A.begin(), A.end(), B.begin(), B.end(), back_inserter(G));

Comment: и элементы множеств - строки. Играет ли это какую-то роль или данная фукнция может быть применима ко всем типам ?

Comment: Строки string или строки char*? Если string - то будет работать, если char* -  то нет, так как сравнение **указателей** - не то же, что сравнение строк.

Comment: push_back у множества отсутствует. Если вы работаете с векторами - то заполните их, отсортируйте и используйте set_intersect. Если со множествами - то используйте для вставки `insert`.

Comment: И очень интересно - почему кому-то не понравился ответ? Вернее, два ответа - @gbg тоже свое получил :) Кто-то, как обычно, не умеет работать с чем-то, но обвиняет в этом это что-то? Типа "В компиляторе ошибка", "библиотека написана неправильно"? :)